# Way to verify the version of an Adobe Flash .FLA file without IDE

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, fla

I'm looking for a way to lightly parse a FLA so that we can validate that the used saved the file as a specific FLA format. IE, Flash 5.0.  We want to integrate this into our Jenkins system so that if a user checks in a later version of the file, say Flash 5.5 or Flash 6.0, it will alert the offending team member to re-save the file as the correct version.

Answer (score 2):

After some more research I realized that as long as you are using Flash 5 or later then it's very easy to get the information that is needed.  You simply need to unzip the fla and then find the XML file that has the info you need.  I just need to write a simple unzip and xml parsing tool.